# Django - OneToOneField Not Populating in Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I’m trying to get the username of the current logged in user using `OneToOneField` to populate in the admin once the user submits a form.

The username should go in the `user` column of `admin.py`.

I’ve tried various methods and still no luck. I’m new to this and this is my first Django application I’m building so I’m not sure what I’m missing.

I’m stuck and have no idea what I’m doing so any help is gladly appreciated.

Can someone please help? What am I missing?

Thanks!

[image]

Code Below:

## user_profile/models

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from users.models import CustomUser


class Listing (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_expiration = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_cvv = models.CharField(max_length=100)    

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = Listing.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

## user_profile/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from user_profile.forms import HomeForm

from user_profile.models import Listing

# Register models here.
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number', 'created', 'updated', 'user']
    list_filter = ['name', 'zip_code', 'created', 'updated', 'user']

admin.site.register(Listing, UserProfileAdmin)
#admin.site.unregister(Listing)
```

## master_application/settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'users.UserProfile'
```

## users/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):

    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        case_insensitive_username_field = '{}__iexact'.format(self.model.USERNAME_FIELD)
        return self.get(**{case_insensitive_username_field: username})


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()`
```

Comment: Does the `CustomUser` model have a method called `__str__` defined in it?

Comment: @xyres No it does not, I just added the models.py where `CustomUser` is located. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't worry about it. `AbstractUser` already has this method and so `CustomUser` model automatically inherits it from there. I think the answer posted by Daniel Roseman would solve your issue.

Comment: @xyres Sounds good. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signal is broken; kwargs will never have a `user` key so the profile will never be created. What you actually want to do is to check that the signal is being called on creation (rather than on update), add then create an instance of Listing:

```
if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = Listing.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])
```

Note, the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE setting has not been used for years, you should remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I made those adjustments now I'm getting `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2019-01-02 02:22:09.745917`. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Can you show the full traceback (as an update to the question, properly formatted).

Comment: Forgive me for being new to django but how do I do that exactly?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Update the question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Looks like after I cleared `db.sqlite3` the error went away. How do i check that the signal is being called on creation?